# Pagination issue in kendo grid

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, pagination, grid

Below code has been used for paginating kendo grid in code behind

In grid i am able to navigate to different pages on page number clicks of bottom of the grid, but the data in the first page remains same in all other pages.

```
  ViewData["total"] = rawData.Count();

            // Apply paging
            if (request.Page > 0)
            {
                gridData = rawData.Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize).OrderByDescending(s => s.UpdateDate).ToList();
            }

                gridData = rawData.Take(request.PageSize).OrderByDescending(s => s.UpdateDate).ToList();


            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = gridData,
                Total = (int)ViewData["total"]
            };

            return Json(result);
```

Let me know , anything wrong with the code. request.Page variable show the correct page number when i navigate to different pages

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

```
ViewData["total"] = rawData.Count();

            // Apply paging
            if (request.Page > 0)
            {
                gridData = rawData.Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize).ToList();
            }

                gridData = rawData.Take(request.PageSize).ToList();


            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = gridData,
                Total = (int)ViewData["total"]
            };

            return Json(result);
```